# CMake command line arguments in a Ninja build

Tags: cmake, command-line-arguments, ninja

I am trying to use Ninja + CMake to build a project.

This project has a custom target that takes additional arguments.

E.g. `make target option=value`

It works fine in `make`, however I am not sure how to get Ninja to take in additional command line arguments.
Is this possible with a Ninja build?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to do directly through Ninja. I just scanned through the Ninja documentation to double check and didn't see anything.

Instead, you could modify CMake cache variables via CMake (see `cmake -D` and `cmake -L`). That way you could change your build on the fly, or create a few different build directories with different settings in each one.